# "dest must be an existing dir " error in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to automate grafana apache_exporter installation using ansible in AWS ec2 instances. While trying to run ansible playbook, i am getting error : "dest must be an existing dir ". Can anyone please help me to solve these.

[image]

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  vars:
    apache_exporter_version: 0.8.0
  tasks:
    - name: create group
      group:
        name: apache_exporter
        state: present
    - name: create user
      user:
        name: apache_exporter
        group: apache_exporter
        createhome: no
        system: yes
        state: present
    - name: create opt directory for prometheus
      file:
        path: /opt/apache_exporter
        state: directory
    - name: download apache exporter
      get_url:
         url: https://github.com/Lusitaniae/apache_exporter/releases/download/v{{ apache_exporter_version }}/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: /opt/apache_exporter
    - name: unarchive apache exporter
      unarchive:
        remote_src: yes
        src: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: /opt/apache_exporter
        creates: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64  
    - name: create symlink to apache exporter
       file:
        path: /usr/local/bin/apache_exporter
        state: link
        src: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64/apache_exporter
    - name: install unit file to systemd
      template:
        src: apache_exporter.service
        dest: /etc/systemd/system/apache_exporter.service
    - name: configure systemd to use service
      systemd:
        daemon_reload: yes
        enabled: yes
        state: started
        name: apache_exporter.service
```

Comment: would you pls show the full `ansible` log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue arise because i was running dry run test with "ansible-playbook --check" parameter, obviously due it file module wasn't creating directory in remote system. Also solved issue in "download apache exporter" section as metioned by @sakibmoon

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  vars:
    apache_exporter_version: 0.8.0
  tasks:
    - name: create group
      group:
        name: apache_exporter
        state: present
    - name: create user
      user:
        name: apache_exporter
        group: apache_exporter
        createhome: no
        system: yes
        state: present
    - name: create opt directory for prometheus
      file:
        path: /opt/apache_exporter
        state: directory
    - name: download apache exporter
      get_url:
        url: https://github.com/Lusitaniae/apache_exporter/releases/download/v{{ apache_exporter_version }}/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    - name: unarchive apache exporter
      unarchive:
        remote_src: yes
        src: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: /opt/apache_exporter
    - name: create symlink to apache exporter
      file:
        path: /usr/local/bin/apache_exporter
        state: link
        src: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64/apache_exporter
    - name: install unit file to systemd
      template:
        src: apache_exporter.service
        dest: /etc/systemd/system/apache_exporter.service
    - name: configure systemd to use service
      systemd:
        daemon_reload: yes
        enabled: yes
        state: started
        name: apache_exporter.service
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, in Ansible `unarchive` module, the path set by `dest` parameter must exist. You need to create it if it does not exist.

Another issue is in your `download apache exporter` task, you are downloading the file to `/opt/apache_exporter` which is a file, but using the same path as `dest` for `unarchive` task.

You need to use a separate name for these paths and create the directory beforehand. The follwoing playbook should solve you issue.

```
- name: download apache exporter
  get_url:
    url: https://github.com/Lusitaniae/apache_exporter/releases/download/v{{ apache_exporter_version }}/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    dest: /opt/apache_exporter.tar.gz
- name: create /opt/apache_exporter directory for unarchiving
  file:
    path: /opt/apache_exporter
    state: directory
- name: unarchive apache exporter
  unarchive:
    remote_src: yes
    src: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    dest: /opt/apache_exporter
    creates: /opt/apache_exporter/apache_exporter-{{ apache_exporter_version }}.linux-amd64
```

Comment: But i am creating directory in the code, please check                                                            
    - name: create opt directory for prometheus
      file:
        path: /opt/apache_exporter
        state: directory

Comment: Sorry it  was my mistake, i was running the ansible-playbook with --check parameter that caused the issue. Parameter i specified was running a dry run in remote system and that's why directory wasn't created. Thanks for specifying "download apache exporter" error,it also solved it.